# Can't overwrite C:\Program Files\Git\etc\ssh

Tags: git, ssh, git-for-windows

I want to clone a git repo and I get an error like this:
Unable to negotiate with 123.123.123.123(IP of server): no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

To solve this, I thought of trying this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340844/how-to-enable-diffie-hellman-group1-sha1-key-exchange-on-debian-8-0

unfortunately, I can't edit the file here: "C:\Program Files\Git\etc\ssh\ssh_config". It says "Unable to save .., Error: access is denied"

chmod won't work:
$ chmod 777 ssh_config
chmod: changing permissions of 'ssh_config': Permission denied

OS: Windows 10, git version 2.28.0.windows.1

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo`? try `sudo nano` or `sudo vim` to open the file for editing.

Comment: I tried, it says:                                                                                                                  $ sudo vi ssh_config
bash: sudo: command not found

Comment: if you are using *git bash* try starting it as administrator. Right click the icon and select **Run as Administrator**, then edit the files.

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, **`chmod 777` is *wrong* and *dangerous.*** Fortunately for you, it's meaningless on Windows anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Try and add a `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config` with a [legacy SSH option](https://www.openssh.com/legacy.html):

```
Host 123.123.123.123
   KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

Then open a new bash session and see if the error persists.